# Error/Exception Handling in Angular5.. ResponseEntity returns null on exception

Tags: angular, rest, exception, response

I am trying to handle exceptions in my angular which is putting data in backend using REST API. Problem is that Response Entity in REST is sending response as null whenever there's an exception although I am setting a proper status code on exception. I think my catch block is not getting called. Below is the code from component to service.

Schedule.component.ts

```ts
create(schedule: Schedule): void {

  this.service.create(schedule).subscribe(data => {
   if (data.created == true) {
       this.gotoSchedules(schedule);
    }
   },
   errorCode => {
      this.statusCode = errorCode;
      console.error(errorCode);
    }
 );//subscribe ends
}
```

schedule.service.ts

```ts
create(schedule: Schedule) : Observable<any> {
  let params:URLSearchParams = this.scheduleParams(schedule);
  let theUrl = window.location.origin + "/o/dsl-rest/dsl/schedule";

  let options = new RequestOptions({responseType: ResponseContentType.Json});
  return this.http.post(theUrl, params, options).map(res => res.json()).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

ScheduleController.java

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/schedule", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public ResponseEntity<String> createSchedule(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response, 
        @FormParam("name") String name,
        @FormParam("days") Integer[] days,
        @FormParam("times") String[] times,
        @FormParam("inside") String[] inside,
        @FormParam("outside") String[] outside,
        @FormParam("screenName") String screenName,
        @FormParam("timeZone") String timeZone, 
        @FormParam("description") String description,
        @FormParam("notifyEmails") String[] notifyEmails,
        @FormParam("notifyInitial") Boolean notifyInitial,
        @FormParam("notifyLate") Boolean notifyLate) throws NamingException
{
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = null;
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Map<String,Object> schedule = createScheduleMap(name, days, times, inside, outside,
            screenName, timeZone, description, notifyEmails, notifyInitial, notifyLate);

    try {
        scheduleService.createSchedule(schedule);
        responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"created\" : true}", HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch(Exception e){
        responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"status\" : error}", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    finally {
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.debug("<< createSchedule() in " + (t2 - t1) + "ms");
    }
    return responseEntity;
}
```

Comment: I never used this AJS version, but shouldn't you `this.http.post(...).subscribe` instead of this weird `.map(...).catch`? Check [this full success/error example](https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling).

Comment: What do you mean "ResponseEntity returns null"? What exactly is null? Where is it null? Is a NullPointerException thrown. If so, where? Please be a little more specific.

Comment: Also, you are mixing JAX-RS concepts and Spring MVC concepts. These two frameworks are not compatible. `@FormParam` is for JAX-RS and `ResponseEntity` is for Spring MVC. Which one are you using? If you are using JAX-RS, then you should be using [`Response`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html), not `ResponseEntity`. If you are using Spring MVC, then you should be using [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html), not `@FormParam`.

Comment: Please take some time to learn the difference between JAX-RS and Spring. I'm voting to close this question is "too broad", as the answer will take explaining to you the differences between Spring MVC and JAX-RS.

Comment: I will surely take your advice to learn the concepts but this is an existing application which I am supposed to just handle exceptions for a particular service. when my service in ScheduleController.java runs successfully, Response returns with a json string having created= true in the below LOC of Schedule.component.ts if (data.created == true) {
       this.gotoSchedules(schedule);
    }. try {
        scheduleService.createSchedule(schedule);
        responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"created\" : true}", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

Comment: Its throwing a NPE while calling service because service object is null and I want to handle such exceptions or some more.try {
        scheduleService.createSchedule(schedule); <----- NPE
        responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"created\" : true}", HttpStatus.OK);
    } Mixing  JAX-RS concepts and Spring MVC concepts is working fine for success and returning the expected ResponseEntity object.. then how come its not working for failures